# How to get data (read) from AWS managed ElasticSearch using java

Tags: amazon-elasticsearch

In AWS IOT, I created a thing (device), and published messages to a topic, say `trucks/truck1234`. I created an Elasticsearch domain and stored those messages to analyse further using Kibana. Up to now, all fine.

Now i want to read the published message data from my application with Java. I’ve followed the steps in this link:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/analyze-device-generated-data-with-aws-iot-and-amazon-elasticsearch-service/

Can anyone please suggest how to achieve it?